# Securing WCF using NTLM CustomBinding and A Custom Principal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security

In securing a WCF service I want to use my active directory custom principal used in the asp.net website hosting the service. All is fine when navigating the website and the Custom Principal is setup using the following code

static void context_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomIdentity identity;
            CustomPrincipal principal = GetPrincipalFromCookie();

```
        if (principal == null)
        {
            ... create principal from active directory
            ... Store Principal in a cookie
        }

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    }
```

HOWEVER when I make a WCF call to my service a login dialog appears removing the line HttpContext.Current.User = principal results in the login dialog not appearing but that is no use to me as I need this in order for WebUserSecurityContext to be populated for my application. I am using customBinding with NTLM

```
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Am I missing a setting in my configuration to prevent this login dialog box or is there a better way? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current` is not considered until `AspNetCompatibilityMode` is enabled. Have you enabled `AspNetCompatibilityMode` for service?

Comment: Hi There AspNetCompatibilityMode is enabled already on the service